# 'import' command, defining of variables

Tags: python, variables, import

I have some program called main.py in which I have defined several variables a,b,c,etc., I also have a program say, xyz.py in which I have written several print statements, functions, loops, etc. which use the variables a,b,c,etc. from main.py. I am using 'import xyz' in main.py to call xyz.py. But it is showing error that 'name a,b,c,etc. are not defined', which is understandable since I have not defined these variables in xyz.py. So please tell me how to use variables in some other file. For example, if I have something like the following,

main.py

```
a=float(input('enter the value of a :: '))
b=float(input('enter the value of b :: '))
if a>1.0:
  import xyz
else:
  print 'exit'
print wxyz(a+b)
print abc(a+b)
```

xyz.py

```
print 'a is'+`a`
print 'b is'+`b`
def wxyz(a):
  return 2*a
def abc(b):
  return 4*b
print wxyz(a)
print abc(b)
while a>b:
  print a+b
  print wxyz(a*b)
  print abc(a*b)
```

Comment: Take a look at the [module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/modules.html) chapter of the python documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious way to do this is to restructure `xyz.py`, something like:

```
def main(a, b):
    print 'a is {0!r}'.format(a) # backticks for repr are deprecated
    print 'b is {0!r}'.format(b)
    print wxyz(a)
    print abc(b)
    # ... etc. 

def wxyz(a):
  return 2 * a # whitespace per PEP-0008

def abc(b):
  return 4 * b

if __name__ = '__main__': # when script is run directly, not imported
    main(1, 2) # or whatever values
```

Now there is nothing that runs directly when the script is imported and you can still call `xyz.main(a, b)` from `main.py`, passing the values in explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I have removed few functions from your main.py to make it simple. I have also executed the programs. The main.py file is :

```
 import xyz
a=float(input('enter the value of a :: '))
b=float(input('enter the value of b :: '))
if a>1.0:
  import xyz
else:
  print 'exit'
```

and your xyz.py file is :

```
from main import a
from main import b
print 'a is',a
print 'b is',b
def wxyz(a):
  return 2*a
def abc(b):
  return 4*b
print wxyz(a)
print abc(b)
while a>b:
  print a+b
```

The output you get is :

```
enter the value of a :: 12
enter the value of b :: 12
a is 12.0
b is 12.0
24.0
48.0
enter the value of a :: 0
enter the value of b :: 0
exit
```

Now is this what you want my friend ?

Comment: you have improved the code. But I think you are running into circular imports which I want to avoid.

Comment: Why are you giving imports aliases that are the same as the name that they started with? Why not just `from main import a, b`?

Comment: Its clearly another issue of your program logic. I think this program of yours is "buggy" which doesn't know when to stop (no condition to exit the program). But I have answered your question of error( showing error that 'name a,b,c,etc. are not defined'). Haven't I ?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry my bad! Yes,we can do that too. I'm new to python and still learning so pardon me.

Answer (score -1):

I think, you don't wanna import but rather execute py code? Then you have to use execfile command

```
execfile( "xyz.py")
```

but i definetely recommend a more Object-Oriented Approach, where you import a class, create an Instance of it and access it's values.

Comment: *import* effectively executes the code of the module, of course there are some differences, but in general a `from xyz import *` would lead to a similar result and should be prefered.

Comment: but execfile() will evaluate everytime, import not necessarry

Comment: And how is that better?

Comment: Exec reads the file unconditionally and does not create a new module. Import does.

Comment: I still see to fail how this is better than import. There is nothing wrong about modules, and if you need to repeatedly execute code it should be placed into a function. Also execfile has to read the file every time, which is time consuming.

Comment: @user1767754 yeah you are right I want to execute xyz.py and execfile() is working. But I read somewhere execfile() is not reliable and is slow, that's why I wanted to do it with 'import'.

Comment: Of course it is not reliable, it puts your code into the calling codes namespace, but your question was, that your code is not working and how you can access the variables.

Comment: However i am out @Zeeker i didn't say that exec is better, but i his case, it is the fastest solution.